# Service Worker: Error Caught (in Promise) TypeError: Request scheme 'data' is unsupported

Tags: javascript, caching, promise, service-worker, service-worker-events

What happens is on the first load of the website fetching and caching does not encounter any problem. But, on refresh (normal reload) Fetch event encounters the problem and shows this on the console log.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request scheme 'data' is unsupported
>       at self.addEventListener.e.respondWith.fetch.then.caches.open.then.cache

I realized that on reload it fetches a `format data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>`which causes the error in the console log.

```
// Call Fetch Event
self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {
  console.log('Service Worker: Fetching');
  e.respondWith(
    fetch(e.request)
      .then(res => {
        // Make copy/clone of response
        const resClone = res.clone();
        // Open cahce
        caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => {
          // Add response to cache
          cache.put(e.request, resClone);
        });
        return res;
      })
      .catch(err => caches.match(e.request).then(res => res))
  );
});
```

I want to avoid this error but I don't know how.

Comment: Not exactly sure, but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49157622/service-worker-typeerror-when-opening-chrome-extension) could point you in the right direction?

Comment: that implies that `e.request` is a data uri - i.e. in the format `data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>`

Comment: Try deleting `.then(res => res)`, which is unnecessary and may well give rise to an uncaught error.

Comment: You might also try turning the `e.respondWith()` and `fetch()` inside-out such that you end up with `e.respondWith(res)` replacing `return res` inside the `.then` callback.

Comment: @JaromandaX you are right. errors occur when the format is data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data> do you have a way to solve the problem?

Comment: since a data uri has all the data you need, you don't need to `fetch` it and caching it won't make any improvement in speed or latency, so just don't do it with data URI

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to open the cache before sending the fetch request so it ensures your cache exists. And you can fallback to your cache response if network fails. The following code will update your cache:

```
e.respondWith(
  caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => {
    cache.match(e.request).then(cacheResponse => {
      const networkFetch = fetch(e.request).then(networkResponse => {
        cache.put(e.request, networkResponse.clone());
        return networkResponse
      });

      return cacheResponse || networkFetch;
    });
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log('error in cache open: ', error)
  })
)
```

Comment: Matt, I tried your code and it updates my cache initially but when I reload the server does not respond anymore. Also, I tried modifying my code and open cache first but the error still exists.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not respond anymore'? Did you stop getting further response from the server? Any chance to paste a link to the code so I can have a look?

Comment: I mean it says that the "This site can’t be reached". I feel like the problem is the data passed to resClone.

Comment: Ok, you might need to double check the value of e.request and see if it is a valid request object.